# How do I keep my database in sync with TICoreDataSync?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, dropbox, ticoredatasync

I've been working on this problem for a while now. Here's what happens:

My app is launched. It already has existing data in the core data store. It then connects to Dropbox using TICoreDataSync.

Then I connect a second device, which also has existing data. I connect it up to Dropbox the same way.

What then happens is that when I sync, it syncs data between the two harmoniously. Any changes i make on one device are sent to the other after a sync on both devices. The problem is, I want the existing data in the database to be uploaded to Dropbox and included in the sync, so both devices have all data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not how TICoreDataSync was intended to work. It will not merge those two store files for you, but will rather pull down the store file uploaded by the first device to the second device and then keep *those* store files in sync. From your description it sounds like you are skipping the whole store upload and download steps during sync manager registration.